# GoDuckDuckGo API Promise

Tags: javascript

I am using the GoDuckDuckGo API for search, which has a promise and console.log passed into it to print a list of returned url's in the console.

I was wondering what I would pass in instead of console.log to store the values in an array?

```
d.search('search query here', {maxPage: 1})
.then(console.log)
```

Comment: Pass in your own callback and do whatever in it?

Comment: Please read some introductory material on the use of callbacks and promises in general.

Comment: ahh apologies guys, promises are completely new to me, got it cracked!

Comment: Are you using [this API library](https://github.com/renruyi/goduckduckgo)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var myArray = [];

d.search('search query here', {maxPage: 1}).then(function(res) {
  myArray = res;
});
```

Do some reading on promises, callbacks, and how to handle API responses.